# Shift+2 or Shift+Anykey isn't working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've a Lenovo Ideapad with Ubuntu 18.04. I tried type my e-mail so I can't put the <kbd>@</kbd> character, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, the number 2 is entered in the field.

All characters are no working, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> doesn't enter <kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: It sounds as if you want the _English (US)_ keyboard layout, but some other layout is effective. So try to [change the keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html).

Comment: may be your `shift` key is dirty, sometimes due to dirt it happens. you should clean it up

Comment: I can use shift to put caps lock letters @eR_

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried it, but not solves.